# Add cells to table in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, insert

I'm looking for a way to have extra cells added to a table, in a sheet with multiple tables. Table A (Column B to F) should get an extra row, under the selected cell. Table B, (Column H to J) should be Fixed: When i add extra cells to row 8 in Table A, Table B should not change. I can only find the EntireRow.Insert, but not for specific cells.

My code so far:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
  Dim anyR As Range
  Set anyR = Selection.SpecialCells(xlVisible)
  Selection.SpecialCells(xlVisible).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
  anyR.Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub
```

But it adds cells to Table B as well. Thanx for having a look into this!

Comment: Are "tables" *actual* tables, or they're just what you're calling these ranges? Does Excel know they're *tables* (it *does* make a difference)?

Answer (score 0):

The following will add a cell beneath the current selection:

```
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Selection.SpecialCells(xlVisible).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
> ```

You're inserting a row in *the worksheet* - that's like right-clicking the row heading and then selecting "insert".

If you have two *tables* on the same sheet, with rows at the insertion point, then yeah, both tables will earn an extra row.

If you want to add rows to *one* table, then work with *the table* instead of `Selection` (you hardly ever really *need* to work with `Selection` anyway):

```
Dim table1 As ListObject
Set table1 = Worksheeets("MyAwesomeSheet").ListObjects(1)

table1.ListRows.Add Position:=5, AlwaysInsert:=True
```

That will insert a new row in the first table of `MyAwesomeSheet`, making a blank 5th row in that table.

Note that this assumes "table" in the OP is referring to actual *tables* in the spreadsheet, i.e. that the target sheet has `ListObject` objects to play with.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! (wasn't working first, because of the extra 'e' in Worksheeets :) )

I would like to have the extra row added, under the current selected cell. How could I achieve that?

Again, thanks for helping!

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

I found a way:

```
    Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":L" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":L" & ActiveCell.Row).Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

In this case, column A to L are selected. 
Thanks for helping!

KR, freek